# How to convert a large Java Project to a Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, dependencies, maven-3

If I create a Java Project at the beginning

some days later,the project becomes larger and the dependency is larger

I want to use maven to manage dependency, what should I do?

I should create (src/main/java  src/test/java   pom.xml) manually or is there some easy way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a large Java project to use maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250536/converting-a-large-java-project-to-use-maven)

Comment: I find use eclipse with m2eclipse:(Java Convert Maven) Project--->Configure--->Convert to Maven Project , add src/main/java src/test/java  manually.(Maven convert Java)project--->Maven--->Disable Maven Nature, edit package manually.This way is easy way to do the work.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse, there is the possibility to convert an existing project into a maven project by `right-click on the root project folder > Configure > Convert to Maven Project`

in IntelliJ, you can convert it too, by selecting everything you need in the project sturcture settings.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps to migrate from Java Project to Maven Java Project.

1) Create new folder "src/main/java" using File>New>Folder option

2) Enable Dependency Management from the context menu of project>M2 MyEclipse Maven

3) In the 2nd wizard,can add required Dependencies to your project if require.

4) Move already existing packages under "src" folder to "src/main/java" folder

5) Run "Maven Install" from the context menu of project, to install the created project in Maven local repository.

As well as visit :

[Using multiple source folders (as intermediate step in a conversion of a large Java project to Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250536/converting-a-large-java-project-to-use-maven)

[How to convert java project to Maven project or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016120/how-to-convert-java-project-to-maven-project-or-similar)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it using [Integration for Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html).
For more info, check [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Converting_Eclipse_Java_Project_to_Maven_Project).

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty Maven project with archetype plugin http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html or IDE. The rest of the job (copying files to proper folders, adding dependencies) needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij Idea, right click on the module to which you need to add Maven support:

[image]

There is also my screencast on how to quickly create a multi-module project with Idea: [How to create an empty multi module Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328778/how-to-create-an-empty-multi-module-maven-project/20163892#20163892) The same technique could be used to manage modules.

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ Idea 2022.3.3, here is how you can do it:

- Right click on root of your project in Explorer on the left side.
- Select "Add framework support" (3rd option from the last as shown in image)
- Choose Maven

[image]